# require_once function.require when I open a component

Tags: php

I'm having this problem to access this component throws me the error:

> Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/home/www/desdeelcuarto.comDScomponentsDScom_muscolDShelpersDShelpers.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/php5.3/lib//php') in /home/www/desdeelcuarto.com/administrator/components/com_muscol/muscol.php on line 15

at line 15 of file muscol.php I have the following:

```
require_once(JPATH_SITE.DS.'components'.DS.'com_muscol'.DS.'helpers'.DS.'helpers.php');
require_once(JPATH_SITE.DS.'components'.DS.'com_muscol'.DS.'helpers'.DS.'alphabets.php')
```

Comment: "...DScomponentsDS..." does not seem suspicious at all to you...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is telling you that the file path you provided is incorrect. If you echo the file path then do you get the expected result?

Your script is treating DS as a string so you should define it before using it:

```
define(DS, '/');

echo JPATH_SITE.DS.'components'.DS.'com_muscol'.DS.'helpers'.DS.'helpers.php';
```

Also the second require_once is missing a semi-colon `;` at the end:

```
require_once(JPATH_SITE.DS.'components'.DS.'com_muscol'.DS.'helpers'.DS.'alphabets.php'); //<--
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, Realize these changes, they displayed this error:  [ /home/www/desdeelcuarto.com/components/com_muscol/helpers/helpers.php
Fatal error: Class AlbumsController contains 5 abstract methods and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (JController::execute, JController::getApplication, JController::getInput, ...) in /home/www/desdeelcuarto.com/administrator/components/com_muscol/controller.php on line 23 ]

Comment: You are welcome but I do not fully understand your comment. Please start a new question and let me know the URL and I will be happy to look over the new error, thank you